# Background image css not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site in which we are replacing menu links with a background image. Here is an example of the css for one of the menu items.

```
  #menu-item-3039{
    width:30px;
    height:20px;
    border:none;
    padding-right:0;
  }
  #menu-item-3039 a{
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  #menu-item-3039 a::before{
    visibility:visible;
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    content:"";
    background-size:20px 20px;
  }
  #menu-item-3039 a::before {
    background-image:url("/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/moodle-icon.png");
  }
```

Is there something very obviously wrong or missing to work with IE11?

It works just great in chrome and firefox, but does not work at all in IE11. I'm not very experienced with IE cross browser support, so it's likely that anything will help.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of ie?

Comment: IE11. Sorry, I'll correct the post.

Comment: Does it output an error? Is your folder correct (should be since you say it is in chrome and firefox) also, maybe try to clear cache. For now, I cant see anything that indicates an error on this piece of code. Is there an example link?

Comment: Probably the visibility from the a is affecting the ::before. Could you provide a fiddle, pen or sample?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors, but then again, I'm not totally sure how to use IE. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. Take a look for me please? http://sandbox.smtchs.org/

Comment: You may not see any errs, but I'm sure that if you inspect with chrome and with ie11 the same div, you'll get very different displays on the css tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE11 is inheriting the `visibility` from the a to their `::before`.

I'd recomend you not to use that rule and use:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-indent: -1000px;
height: 20px;
display: block;
```

instead. This way you are hidding the text (what I think that is what you really want to do) and not affecting the background.

Comment: If I do that, the original content of those menu items appears again, and I'm left with both the icons and the title showing up in the header.